# Git pull merge issue with remote origin

Tags: github

I did `git fetch` and `git fetch --all` but there was no output for the same. after that when I do git pull again I get the below error again.

I am willing to fetch the origin from the remote to my local.

I even did this below but still there is an error.

```
[root@connect /myurl/fd-ansible]# git fetch origin master
Password:
From https://github.com/myurl/fd-ansible
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
[root@connect /myurl/fd-ansible]# git clean -df
[root@connect /myurl/fd-ansible]# git pull
Password:
Updating 8bf6b66..a0b2167
error: Your local changes to 'group_vars/system1' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

**Edited with @Stephen Kitt solution**

```
[root@connect /myurl/fd-ansible]# git checkout group_vars/system1
[root@connect /myurl/fd-ansible]# git pull
Password:
Updating 8bf6b66..a0b2167
Fast-forward
 cmdb/vm.csv |  118 +++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------------
 group_vars/system1       |   56 ++++++++++++++++++++++++
 2 files changed, 115 insertions(+), 59 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Use `git fetch` instead, not that that will fully resolve the situation—you need to *understand* Git to use it properly.  Also, this question would do better on StackOverflow than here.

Comment: How do you resolve it? Well that depends on that you want to do with the changes - do you want to keep them, add them to the repo or ignore them?

Comment: @Wildcard I attempted to run `git fetch` it was executed without any output. Does that mean it is done with the merge part.

Comment: @muru I want to overwrite my local file. let me know how can i do that.

Comment: You really need to read the documentation.  However, for a starting point which will bring you up from knowing *absolutely nothing* about Git to actually being able to *understand* the documentation (which is notoriously difficult for beginners), understand how commits are related and what a commit *is,* I would recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6Se3jH60dA).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-to-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files

Comment: Question edited with the latest query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overwrite your local file (losing your changes):

```
git checkout group_vars/system1
```

Then you should be able to `git pull`.